# I cannot deploy my project to the server via ci/cd

Tags: docker, deployment, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have a server running gitlab-runner in docker. I wrote a ci/cd for the build and deployment. The build is going well. But the deploy doesn't want to work at all.
I try to ssh into my server and make commands to start the project but I get an error:

```
ssh: connect to host <server_ip> port <server_port>: Operation timed out
```

Help me to fix the Deploy command to my server.

This is my deploy script:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  tags:
    - test_runner
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p <server_port> "echo 'good'"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p <server_port> "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p <server_port> "docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p <server_port> "docker container rm -f <container_name> || true"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p <server_port> "docker run -d -p 80:80 --name <container_name> $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://$SERVER_IP
  only:
    - develop
```

The ID_RSA variable stores the ssh private key